# Trouble edit and save data from one Activity to another Activity

Tags: java, android

Currently working on an android application using php as an API to retrive data from SQL.

I am able to view on one activity but when I go to next activity for edit, it only displays empty content.

I posted the full code in Code Review site [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14223/trouble-edit-and-save-data-from-one-activity-to-another-activity).

Comment: I don't see where your calling putExtra(), to put data in your intent. Am I missing it?

Comment: Ryan, could you kindly explain me how to use in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(ViewRequestActivity, EditRequestActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("DATA", "" + your_value);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

In EditRequestActivity get this "DATA" value.

```
    Bundle receiveBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String data= receiveBundle.getString("DATA");
```

And then set this value in your edit text.

```
    txtTitle.setText(data);
```